# Button Highlighting and Scroll Issue in Phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am New to Phonegap Development, I am Using jQuery mobile to create my UI. I have two Issues here,

1. Response of button for touch event is very slow. Why..?
2. I have Created a form with some elements like 2 Inputs text type, 2 Button one after another.

M problem is when I click on input, the keyboard popup makes the page move up, that's OK but when I press the keyboard resign button, the page stay little up.

Can you please help me out..!
and how to Optimize the responsiveness of JQuery mobile UI. I have completely avoided the images.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can follow [this link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-remove-the-300ms-delay-when-clicking-on-a-link-in-jquery-mobile) to remove the delay (300ms) from the click event.

And for the second one, i hope you are facing this issue for android. if so, then you need some changes to be done on the AndroidManifest.xml

Use below android property in application tag,

```
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Will look something like

```
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Sorry, But i am facing this issue for iPhone and iPad.

Comment: Ok..Can you check if you have used overflow: hidden to body or html ?

Comment: i have removed all Default css created by temeplete.